# Change stroke width from Milimeters to map units

Tags: pyqgis, pyqgis-3

I would like to change the stroke width from mm to map units. The code below is mainly taken from ThomasG77's answer from a previous question. I only found a way to change the units of Labels unfortunately.

[Use colums in attribute table to set colors and line thickness directly automatic](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/371465/use-colums-in-attribute-table-to-set-colors-and-line-thickness-directly-automati)

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()

# Get colors in rgb codes from Attribute table
layer.renderer().symbol().symbolLayer(0).dataDefinedProperties().property(QgsSymbolLayer.PropertyStrokeColor).setExpressionString("\"Farben\" || ',255'")
layer.renderer().symbol().symbolLayer(0).dataDefinedProperties().property(QgsSymbolLayer.PropertyStrokeColor).setActive(True)


# Get Stroke width from Attribute table
layer.renderer().symbol().symbolLayer(0).dataDefinedProperties().property(QgsSymbolLayer.PropertyStrokeWidth).setExpressionString("\"Linien\"")
layer.renderer().symbol().symbolLayer(0).dataDefinedProperties().property(QgsSymbolLayer.PropertyStrokeWidth).setActive(True)


# Refresh rendering of the layer
layer.triggerRepaint()
```

Comment: I used your solution in a loop but for me it is not working.
The units of the layer remain Milimeters.
Even when I change manually the Map Units to something else and run the script it changes to Milimeters
[![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ese6B.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ese6B.png) Here is how I used your suggestion: for a in layers_fimport: #print (a.name()) # get the layer's features as an iterator features = table.getFeatures() # Seach for a specific Layer in the table for feat in features: attrs = feat.attributes() if attrs[0] == a.name(): R = attrs(https://

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found it.

```
layer.renderer().symbol().symbolLayer(0).setWidthUnit(QgsUnitTypes.RenderMapUnits)
```

does the job