# Automating QGIS legend with RGB fields

Tags: qgis, symbology, legend, rgb

I have a shapefile layer with R,G,B fields and used the following expression to set the symbol color.
[image]

Surprisingly, it worked right away. However, even though the colors are applied in the canvas, they are not reflected in the legend. If I select categories instead of single symbol,the result is the same: the symbol colors doesn't match. I would like to know if there's some efficient way to to get the correct colors for the legend symbols.

[image]

Here's a video that shows the process: https://streamable.com/2l35dc

Comment: That's the expected/intended behaviour - QGIS does not automatically generate categorised symbols in the legend when you use a data-defined override. I believe the only way to efficiently generate all the legend symbols is to use Python, such as in this answer: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/371465/use-colums-in-attribute-table-to-set-colors-and-line-thickness-directly-automati/371494#371494 (where rgb is stored in one field).